# How can I fixe missing keys errors?

Tags: apt, keys

I really need your help as a fresher in linux :/

I have deleted the folder `trusted.gpg.d` located in `/etc/apt/` and also deleted `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Now when I try to update I receive these errors:

```
Err:2 LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
Err:3 LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
Err:4 LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
Err:5 LINKppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg3>**
Get:9 LINKmaven.xwiki.org stable/ Packages [352 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
E: The repository 'LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
E: The repository 'LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
E: The repository 'LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg1>** NO_PUBKEY  **<My_Key_Missingg2>**
E: The repository 'LINKpt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: LINKppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY **<My_Key_Missingg3>**
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

### **NOTE -** I've changed http:// to LINK to be able to submit this question.

I have tried a bunch of suggestion like:

1 - `apt install extundelete` to recover the files. And receive this error: `E: Unable to locate package extundelete`

2 - `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys **<MY KEY>**` (I've tried with and without hkp://)

3 - `apt-get install ubuntu-keyring` and similar errors about NO_PUBKEYS

4 - `gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key **<MY KEY>**`
`gpg -a --export **<MY KEY>** | sudo apt-key add` . and got de error: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of file; gpg: WARNING: nothing exported gpg: .: read error: Is a directory gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

5- I have already used this one too unsuccessfully
`sudo apt update 2>&1 1>/dev/null | sed -ne 's/.*NO_PUBKEY //p' | while read key; do if ! [[ ${keys[*]} =~ "$key" ]]; then sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key"; keys+=("$key"); fi; done`

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: First why did you delete what you did? Were you trying to do something?

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to install a wiki software, and then I uninstalled correctly using the apt-get --purge remove <wikinameapp> and apt-get --purge autoremove. When I tried to install it again, and I noticed that was some other content remains from the previous installation. I follow the path where was the duplicated files (/etc/apt/sources.list.d) and removed thinking that all the contents were installed by me.  I also did a ls -ls to see the hours of the last installations and the folder trusted.gpg.d was in the same time, so I did delete that also thinking that was installed by me.

Comment: Thanks David, I know that I messed up.....

Comment: Time for a complete re install I would suggest.

Comment: Full normal output `sudo apt update` is needed. Upload it to pastebin. Do you use proxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)